# Can't insert Data to Database via PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am building a "insert to Database" Page.
I Have 2 Datepicker and one Dropdown box.

When I am Running My Code The Value which will be send is NULL for every 3 Page-Elements.

`:P8_DATE_START` is a Datepicker.
`:P8_DATE_END` is a Datepicker.
`:P8_COOKD` is a Dropdown with an ID.

My Code:

```
INSERT INTO HOOR_Main (ID, NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, DESCRIPTION, TASK_OWNER, STATUS)
VALUES (13, 1, :P8_DATE_START, :P8_DATE_END, 'Das ist ein Test via SQL', :P8_COOKD, 1);
```

My Database:
[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX1X7.png)

How can I Send the Values of the Page-Elements to Database?

**EDIT:** It is also not possible to Insert only `:P8_COOKD`. So I think the Problem is by getting the Information from the Element.

Comment: Don't use NVARCHAR2, use VARCHAR2 instead.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? Where exactly is that code ? In a page process of type pl/sql ? What is the execution point of that code ? Have you checked debug ?

Comment: I am using a Dynamic Action (Run PL/SQL Code, while True). I am running the Code after Inserting the Data by Click on a Button. The Error Message is: `Ajax call returned server error ORA-01400: Inserting NULL in ("WSHOMEORGAN". "HOOR_MAIN". "TASK_OWNER") not possible for PL/SQL code execution.`

Comment: Did you put P8_COOKD in “ items to submit “ for your pl/sql action ? That is how it is passed to the database session.

Comment: @KoenLostrie Would you write this as an Answer? Then i can mark it as Solution :) It is working now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the database session to pick up the value of a page item in a dynamic action, you need to put it in "Items to Submit" for the pl/sql action.

--Koen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to convert first your output from Datepicker? Something like:

```
INSERT INTO HOOR_Main (ID, NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, DESCRIPTION, TASK_OWNER, STATUS)
VALUES (13, 1, TO_DATE(:P8_DATE_START, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), TO_DATE(:P8_DATE_END, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Das ist ein Test via SQL', :P8_COOKD, 1);
```

Comment: I Tried it already. It is also not possible to Insert only :P8_COOKD. So i think the Problem is by getting the Information from the Element.